# Correct way to trigger radio button handler with jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have two radio buttons. Depending on which one is checked, I want to show or hide a `<div>` on the page. So I created this handler.

```
$(function () {
    $('input[name="Search.LatestOnly"]').on('change', function () {
        if ($(this).val() == 'true')
            $('#date-section').hide(400);
        else
            $('#date-section').show(400);
    });
});
```

This works fine. But I want to set the `<div>` visibility to the correct state when the page loads, so I added this line:

```
$('input[name="Search.LatestOnly"]:checked').trigger();
```

This produces run-time errors that aren't meaningful to me.

> jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot convert undefined or null to object TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
> at hasOwnProperty ()
> at Object.trigger (https://localhost:44377/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js:2:70619)
> at HTMLInputElement. (https://localhost:44377/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js:2:72108)
> at Function.each (https://localhost:44377/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js:2:2976)
> at S.fn.init.each (https://localhost:44377/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js:2:1454)
> at S.fn.init.trigger (https://localhost:44377/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js:2:72084)
> at HTMLDocument. (https://localhost:44377/Data/Search:206:58)
> at e (https://localhost:44377/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js:2:30005)
> at t (https://localhost:44377/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js:2:30307) undefined
> S.Deferred.exceptionHook @ jquery.min.js:2
> t @ jquery.min.js:2
> setTimeout (async)
> (anonymous) @ jquery.min.js:2
> c @ jquery.min.js:2
> fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2
> fire @ jquery.min.js:2
> c @ jquery.min.js:2
> fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2
> ready @ jquery.min.js:2
> B @ jquery.min.js:2
> jquery.min.js:2

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
> at hasOwnProperty ()
> at Object.trigger (jquery.min.js:2)
> at HTMLInputElement. (jquery.min.js:2)
> at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
> at S.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2)
> at S.fn.init.trigger (jquery.min.js:2)
> at HTMLDocument. (Search:206)
> at e (jquery.min.js:2)
> at t (jquery.min.js:2)

Can anyone tell me how to initialize my HTML so that the `<div>` is hidden or displayed once the page is loaded?

Comment: Maybe `$('input[name="Search.LatestOnly"]:checked').trigger();` is executing too quickly? Are you able to edit the html and css, or just the js?

Comment: @asyncawait: I can edit the HTML. But I put this code within `$(function() { ... });`, so it should be ready to go.

Comment: Can you log the element before you trigger it? That can rule it out. 

I would suggest using the `checked` html attribute for the initial state, and either css to make the element visible, later changed by js, or changed immediately by js with `.show`

Comment: @asyncawait: I don't know what you mean by *log the element*. I could hide it with CSS, but then it would be in the wrong state if it should be shown.

Comment: When I say "log the element" I mean, `console.log($('input[name="Search.LatestOnly"]:checked'))` in your code before the error to see the result in the console.

Comment: @asyncawait: In my handler there, `this` is a Window object instead of one of my radio buttons. Aside from that, the errors have already occurred when my handler is called.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238160/discussion-between-async-await-and-jonathan-wood).

Answer (score 1):

Stupid me. I forgot to include the name of the event.

```
$('input[name="Search.LatestOnly"]:checked').trigger('change');
```

Thanks to a totally unhelpful error message there, I wasted a bunch of time on a very stupid mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example of show / hide connected to a radio input, that checks the current checked value and runs immediately, as well as adds the event listener. Hopefully this adds some perspective to your own project. Unfortunately without being able to recreate the error it will be difficult to give more specific advice. I would always be happy to look over your project separately from this answer.

I did a cheeky little thing where I made the value of the radio the desired method just to cut down on steps where I would usually have to write a conditional to handle understanding the value.

```js
$(() => {
  const content = $("div");
  const shown = $("input[name='test']:checked").val();
  const handleShow = (method, t = 200) => content[method](t);
  handleShow(shown, 0);
  $("input").on("change", function () {
    const shown = $(this).val();
    handleShow(shown);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  conditional content
</div>
<label> Show
  <input type="radio" name="test" value="show" checked>
</label>
<label> Hide
  <input type="radio" name="test" value="hide">
</label>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you are doing with handleShow there. I was hoping to avoid "cheeky little things". That's why I don't understand why trigger() can't work.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would include an example of accomplishing this goal in vanilla javascript as well, as a resource for anyone else that stumbles across the question.

Two things to keep in mind with this answer, the max-height of 1rem in css will not work for all containers. You could dynamically set the max-height, or use something impossibly high (which would affect animations)

This does not check the state of "checkedness" upon initial launch, it assumes it will always have the same state upon launch.

```js
(() => {
  const $ = str => [...document.querySelectorAll(str)];
  const content = $("div")[0];
  const radios = $("input[name='test']");
  radios.forEach(radio => {
    radio.addEventListener("input", e => {
      const val = e.target.value;
      if (val === "show") content.classList.remove("hidden");
        else content.classList.add("hidden");
    });
  });
})();
```

```css
div {
  max-height: 1rem;
  transition: max-height .2s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.hidden {
  max-height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  conditional content
</div>
<label> Show
  <input type="radio" name="test" value="show" checked>
</label>
<label> Hide
  <input type="radio" name="test" value="hide">
</label>
```

Comment: Assuming a state on "initial launch" is exactly what I need to avoid. And I don't understand why trigger() can't be used.